# return some vertices in Shape Key their Basis coordinates

Tags: shape-keys

Let's say I've spent time editing may vertices to a desired position for a Shape Key, and after some test renders, I want to select one or more of these and get them back to their original (Basis, reference) coordinates.  Is there a way to select and say "this vertex back to Basis"?  Even more productive, to select *several* (a subset) of vertices of those changed by a SK and return those several back to Basis?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the vertices, go into the *Vertex panel > Blend from Shape*:

[image]

Then in the *Operator* box choose the *Basis* shapekey and disable the *Add* option:

[image]